# My windows Task Schdulrer is raising this error "0xE0434352"

Tags: kernel, .net, task-scheduler, eventviewer

I have windows server 2012 R2, and i have some tasks inside Windows Task scheduler which use to work well, but yesterday they start to return this error `0xE0434352`, as follow:-

[image]

I checked the Event Viewer logs and i found this error:-

```
Faulting application name: RunsHourly.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0xbc3caebe
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.19724, time stamp: 0x5ec50c3e
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000156e8
Faulting process id: 0x9f8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6a09f2cb0bcb1
Faulting application path: C:\batchfiles\RunHourly\RunsHourly.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 719d6328-0c92-11eb-8136-0050568b4e10
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 




Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          12/10/2020 14:54:28
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      *****.ad-itservices.intra
Description:
Faulting application name: RunsHourly.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0xbc3caebe
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.19724, time stamp: 0x5ec50c3e
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000156e8
Faulting process id: 0x9f8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d6a09f2cb0bcb1
Faulting application path: C:\batchfiles\RunHourly\RunsHourly.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 719d6328-0c92-11eb-8136-0050568b4e10
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: 
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Application Error" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>100</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-10-12T13:54:28.000000000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>893887</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>******.ad-itservices.intra</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>RunsHourly.exe</Data>
    <Data>1.0.0.0</Data>
    <Data>bc3caebe</Data>
    <Data>KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>6.3.9600.19724</Data>
    <Data>5ec50c3e</Data>
    <Data>e0434352</Data>
    <Data>000156e8</Data>
    <Data>9f8</Data>
    <Data>01d6a09f2cb0bcb1</Data>
    <Data>C:\batchfiles\RunHourly\RunsHourly.exe</Data>
    <Data>C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll</Data>
    <Data>719d6328-0c92-11eb-8136-0050568b4e10</Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
    <Data>
    </Data>
  </EventData>
```

any advice please?

Also when i manually run the `.exe` file, i got this exception inside the CMD window:-

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembl
y 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client, Version=16.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToke
n=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest
definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x801
31040)
   at RunsHourly.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

although i have the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client` inside the same folder as follow:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you use relative folder (reading or write files) in your program?
Then when you setup a scheduler job, you will see two fields "program/script" and "Start in(Optional)". You need also to put the program folder path in Start in(Optional). That means your program will run that folder. If you will not do that and your program start not in directory with exe, it will not find files that are located in it.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX9Y0.png)